# how to determine which process is using a queue?

Tags: c, linux, unix, ipc

I have a message queue id, i need to determine which processes are reading from and writing to that queue.
Is there a possible option that can be used with 'ipcs'?

```
ipcs -q|grep qid
```

this doesn't provide those details.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can only retrieve the last PID that called `msgsnd()` and the last PID that called `msgrcv()` for the specified System V message queue.

You can use:

```
ipcs -q -p
```

It will output:

```
------ Message Queues PIDs --------
msqid      owner      lspid      lrpid
```

Where:

- **`lspid`** - PID of last `msgsnd()`
- **`lrpid`** - PID of last `msgrcv()`

Comment: it's showing 0 in both lspid ,lrpid. Is it because no process has read or written to the queues?

Comment: @arjungaur Exactly.